# Handling Race condition in CQRS/ES with read-side

Tags: domain-driven-design, race-condition, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am building an app for managing a health clinic.

We find a race condition case when an appointment is scheduled, and until now, none of team members reaches a solution.

When an appointment is scheduled, some business rules need to be verified:

- cannot be scheduled to the same time as another with the same doctor or same patient
- doctors can only attend N appointments in the month
- in a week, doctors can only attend N appointments

So, the first approach we think is to create an aggregate that will hold all appointments, responsible for schedule them, but this aggregate will be huge and technically is not acceptable.

The second approach, and the current one, is to create Appointment as an Aggregate Root, and then validate it using a domain service (interface in domain layer and implementation in infra layer), which queries the read side.

Today its look like:

- Inside command handler, instantiate new Appointment, passing a domain service in its constructor
- Appointment calls domain service, which query the read side and validate the rules. However, race conditions can occurs here (two appointments being scheduled at the same time, as the two do not see each other, both will be created).
- If domain service validate the rules, then the Appointment is created, but with status PENDING, and a domain event AppointmentRequested is fired.
- On the read side, this event was subscribed and a projection is inserted in the read db (status = PENDING). In same transaction, a command CompleteAppointmentSchedule is inserted in my outbox and soon is sent and received asynchronously by the write side.
- write side handles the command calling appointment.CompleteSchedule(domainService). The same domain service passed when instantiate a new appointment is passed again to the appointment. But, now, the appointment will already be in the read db, and will be possible to check the business rules.

Is it correct to use read side this way? We cannot think another the way to check this rules without using the read side. A team member suggested that we could create a private read-side for our write-side, and use it instead of a read-side in these cases, but, as we use EventStore DB, we would have to create another database like the one we use on the read-side (pgsql) to be able to do it that way on this private read-side.

Comment: You can use SAGA for managing this. Two AppointmentCreated events published, then you need to update the read side, but in the read side, you have unique constraints, so one of them can not be saved, then publish another event to canceling the second AppointmentCreated event

Answer (score 1):

> I am building an app for managing a health clinic.

Reserve an office, get the entire team together, and watch [Trench Talk: Evolving a Model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7StN-vNjRSw).  Yves Reynhout has been doing (and talking about) domain driven design, and *his* domain is appointment scheduling for healthcare.

> When an appointment is scheduled, some business rules need to be verified:

> - cannot be scheduled to the same time as another with the same doctor or same patient
> - doctors can only attend N appointments in the month in a week,
> - doctors can only attend N appointments

One of the things you are going to need to discuss with your domain experts; do you need to prevent scheduling conflicts, or do you need to *identify* scheduling conflicts and resolve them?

Recommended reading:

- [Race Conditions Don't Exist](https://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/) - Udi Dahan, 2010
- [Memories, Guesses, and Apologies](https://web.archive.org/web/20100722052618/https://blogs.msdn.com/b/pathelland/archive/2007/05/15/memories-guesses-and-apologies.aspx) - Pat Helland, 2007

---

That said, you are really close to a common answer.

You make the your checks against a cached copy of the calendar, to avoid the most common collisions (note that there is still a race condition, when you are checking the schedule at the same time somebody else is trying to cancel the conflicting appointment).  You then put an appointment request message into a queue.

Subscribing to the queue is a Service-as-in-SOA, which is *the* technical authority for all information related to scheduling.  That service has its own database, and checks its own authoritative copy of everything before committing a change.

The critical different here is that when the service is working directly with *locked* instances of the data.  That might be because the event handler in the service is the only process that has write permissions on the authoritative data (and is itself handling only one message at a time), or it might be because the event handler locks *all* of the data necessary to ensure that the result of the write is still consistent with the business rules (conflicting writes competing for the same lock, thus ensuring that data changes are controlled).

In effect, all attempts to change the authoritative calendar data are (logically) serialized, to ensure that the writes cannot conflict with each other.

In the language of CQRS, all of this locking is happening in the *write* model of the calendar service.  Everybody else works from *unlocked* copies of the data, which are provided by the read model (with some modest plumbing involved in copying data change from the write model to the read model).